# How do I open files that are outside the home folder with Snap programs?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I had installed some programs using Snap packages in Kubuntu 16.10. I installed programs that open files, such as VLC and LibreOffice. But I can't open my files located out of the Home folder. In other words, I can't open my files in my External HD and another devices connected in my PC using these snap programs. How can I fix it?

Comment: We are working with upstream to include new functionality in their VLC snap for accessing external HDD. In the meantime, if you like to play around with it, I would suggest building your own VLC snap based on https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/blob/master/vlc/snapcraft.yaml and adding the `udisks2` interface plug http://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/reference/interfaces

Answer (score 0):

apparently there's also a removable-media interface which wasn't being used by the VLC snap and is being added. This might be a better fit than the udisk2 one?

Cheers,

-Loïc Minier